# How to force Bazel to stamp all binaries?

Tags: go, rules, bazel

The documentation for `--stamp` in the [Bazel User Manual](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html) states:

> Specifying --stamp does not force affected targets to be rebuilt, if their dependencies have not changed.

Is there a way to force affected targets to be built so that all output binaries have the same stamp, even if their dependencies have not changed?

The specific use case is that I'm building a large number of related Go binaries (using [rules_go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go)), and I'd like to reliably stamp them all with the same version number (taken from the latest git commit hash). I could do a `bazel clean` beforehand, but this somewhat defeats the point of using Bazel :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need them to be of the latest version?

Comment: We actually had to work hard not to rebuild everything just to put a stamp on it, as it wouldn't scale and would spoil the caches. Can this be solved on a different level, not in bazel?

Comment: We need them all to be of the latest version because other tooling relies on this. This is for builds for our integration environment that should reflect the latest state of the `master` branch. Every build binary's buildstamp should be the git commit hash of `master` . Unfortunately other tooling and developers get confused if they see different buildstamps in different binaries.

A possible workaround is to delete all binaries and rebuild them: `bazel clean $(bazel query 'kind("go_binary rule", //...)')` followed by `bazel build`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add the `.git/refs/heads/<release branch>` file as a data input?  Then when the commit changes, your inputs will change "automatically."  You could wrap it in a genrule to add some check or avoid rebuilding everything on the development branch:

```
genrule(
    name = "stamper",
    outs = ["stamper.out"],
    srcs = [
        ".git/HEAD",
        ".git/refs/heads/master",
    ],
    cmd = """
if [[ $$(cat $(location :.git/HEAD)) = "refs: refs/heads/<release branch>" ]]; then
  cat $(location :.git/refs/heads/master)
else
  # If we're not on the release branch, don't uncache things on commit.
  echo "dev"  
fi
""",
)
```

There's [a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3041) for forcing actions to be rerun that you could track/comment on, if interested.